# PHP SMTP mail need to config on sitemailxchange.gate.com is my code is correct

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, mailer

**is my code correct  or give some suggestion for sitemailxchange host and with port number..? i have check most of combination .
Thanks in advance.**

```
    require("class.phpmailer.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer();


    $mail->IsSMTP();

    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
    //$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.sitemailxchange.gate.com";      
    $mail->Port       = 587;               
    $mail->Username   = "yourmail@domain.com";  
    $mail->Password   = "password";      

    $mail->SetFrom('yourmail@domain.com');

    $mail->AddReplyTo("yourmail@domain.com");

    $mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp (Gmail), basic";

    $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message,  viewer!";     
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    $address = "yourmail@domain.com";
    $mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
      echo "Message sent!";
    }
```

Comment: can you tell what type of error are you getting enable debug mode using this $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;

Comment: Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: smtp.sitemailxchange.gate.com.com is your host is correct why you are having double .com seems like your host is not listening

Comment: i have updated  my code in above  but again the same error is coming

Comment: your code seems fine since i am not much aware of sitemailexchange i would suggest you to check your code by sending mail using a gmail smtp credentials ... and if you have any documentation from the sitemailexchange plz check it for any restrictions on request or port and host.

Comment: You are using an old version of PHPMailer. Update it.